# Chain several WHEN conditions in a scalable way in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, conditional-statements, method-chaining

I have a dictionary (variable `pats`) with many `when` arguments: conditions and values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("ė",), ("2",), ("",), ("@",)], ["col1"])

pats = {
  r"^\d$"          :"digit",
  r"^\p{L}$"       :"letter",
  r"^[\p{P}\p{S}]$":"spec_char",
  r"^$"            :"empty"
}

whens = (
    F.when(F.col("col1").rlike(list(pats.keys())[0]), pats[list(pats.keys())[0]])
     .when(F.col("col1").rlike(list(pats.keys())[1]), pats[list(pats.keys())[1]])
     .when(F.col("col1").rlike(list(pats.keys())[2]), pats[list(pats.keys())[2]])
     .when(F.col("col1").rlike(list(pats.keys())[3]), pats[list(pats.keys())[3]])
     .otherwise(F.col("col1"))
)
df = df.withColumn("col2", whens)

df.show()
# +----+---------+
# |col1|     col2|
# +----+---------+
# |   ė|   letter|
# |   2|    digit|
# |    |    empty|
# |   @|spec_char|
# +----+---------+
```

I'm looking for a scalable way to *chain* all the `when` conditions, so I wouldn't need to write a line for every key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Without `reduce`**

  ```py
  whens = F
  for k, v in pats.items():
      whens = whens.when(F.col("col1").rlike(k), v)
  whens = whens.otherwise(F.col("col1"))
  ```

  Full code:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame([("ė",), ("2",), ("",), ("@",)], ["col1"])

  pats = {
    r"^\d$"          :"digit",
    r"^\p{L}$"       :"letter",
    r"^[\p{P}\p{S}]$":"spec_char",
    r"^$"            :"empty"
  }

  whens = F
  for k, v in pats.items():
      whens = whens.when(F.col("col1").rlike(k), v)
  whens = whens.otherwise(F.col("col1"))

  df = df.withColumn("col2", whens)

  df.show()
  # +----+---------+
  # |col1|     col2|
  # +----+---------+
  # |   ė|   letter|
  # |   2|    digit|
  # |    |    empty|
  # |   @|spec_char|
  # +----+---------+
  ```
- **Using `reduce`**

  ```py
  from functools import reduce

  whens = reduce(
      lambda acc, p: acc.when(F.col("col1").rlike(p), pats[p]),
      pats.keys(),
      F
  ).otherwise(F.col("col1"))
  ```

  Full code:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  from functools import reduce
  df = spark.createDataFrame([("ė",), ("2",), ("",), ("@",)], ["col1"])

  pats = {
    r"^\d$"          :"digit",
    r"^\p{L}$"       :"letter",
    r"^[\p{P}\p{S}]$":"spec_char",
    r"^$"            :"empty"
  }

  whens = reduce(
      lambda acc, p: acc.when(F.col("col1").rlike(p), pats[p]),
      pats.keys(),
      F
  ).otherwise(F.col("col1"))

  df = df.withColumn("col2", whens)

  df.show()
  # +----+---------+
  # |col1|     col2|
  # +----+---------+
  # |   ė|   letter|
  # |   2|    digit|
  # |    |    empty|
  # |   @|spec_char|
  # +----+---------+
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code snippet as a work around for this.

```
def parse_if_else_statements(sdf:SDF, statements:List[tuple]) -> SDF:
    """
    Chaining if else statements with when & otherwise in pyspark

    Parameters:
    ----------
    sdf: Spark DataFrame
        The dataframe to parse the if else statements.

    statements: List[tuple]
        The if else statements as a list of tuples. The order of tuple elements are
        col_name, if_condition, do, else_do  
        
    """
    
    # TODO account for nested if else statements  
    for statement in statements:
        col_name, if_cond, do, else_do = statement
        sdf = sdf.withColumn(col_name, f.when(if_cond, do).otherwise(else_do))
    return sdf
```

Then you can pass your conditional statements as

```
statements = [
# (column_name, if_condition, do, else_do  )
('Col A', col('Col B')=='90', col('col C'), col('Col D')), 
]
```