# Pyspark: how to replace column values with dict when types of the keys and values are different

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapping

I have a pySpark dataframe with a column of integers. I also have a mapping dict from integers to strings like

```
{1: 'A', 
 2: 'B', 
 3: 'C'}
```

I would like to get a new column from the original column using this mapping. How to do this?

I tried to use the replace function, but it casts the new values into the same datatype as the original. I think I could first cast the integers into strings, but it would be nice to know a more general way to do this.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html

I am a newbie with pySpark and probably just missing something very simple. :) Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980704/pyspark-create-new-column-with-mapping-from-a-dict

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72865766/8279585) might be helpful. it helps create a new column which will preserve the new data type.

Comment: Thanks @ScootCork , a mapping expression created by `create_map` worked nicely!

Answer (score 0):

a `when().otherwise()` can be used here, chained with [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (from `functools`).

```
data_sdf = spark.range(3).toDF('num')

# +---+
# |num|
# +---+
# |  0|
# |  1|
# |  2|
# +---+

replace_dict = {
    1: 'A', 
    2: 'B', 
    3: 'C'
}
```

We can use the `reduce()` to chain the `when()` statements.

```
when_statement = reduce(lambda x, y: x.when(func.col('num') == y, replace_dict[y]), 
                        replace_dict.keys(), 
                        func.when(func.col('num') == None, func.lit(None))
                        ). \
    otherwise(func.lit(None))

print(when_statement)
# Column<'CASE WHEN (num = NULL) THEN NULL WHEN (num = 1) THEN A WHEN (num = 2) THEN B WHEN (num = 3) THEN C ELSE NULL END'>

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('replaced_vals', when_statement). \
    show()

# +---+-------------+
# |num|replaced_vals|
# +---+-------------+
# |  0|         null|
# |  1|            A|
# |  2|            B|
# +---+-------------+
```

---

[`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) applies a function to an iterable recursively, and its signature is `reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`, meaning first the function which is our `when()` statement, then comes the iterable or our dictionary keys which will be used to pull replacing values from the dictionary recursively. Last part is optional but important in this case - it is the initial value that is at the top of the chain. In this case, because we wanted a `func.when().when()....otherwise()`, we passed the first `func.when()` as an initial value and the rest of them will be chained recursively using the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @samkart ! I solved my case using `create_map`, but I will check this out and test to learn more!